# How to get object array value

Tags: angular, typescript

How to get object array value from data array?  Below is my code

**Component**

```
FmtNews(mediasource) {
    let body = mediasource;
    console.log("Test body:" +body)
    this.commonService.getTopNews(body)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      if (res['status'].code === 102) {
        // this.headerService.isLoading = false;
         console.log(res['data'])
      }
    });
}
```

When I `console.log(res['data'])` I got example like this.

```
(4)[..]
 0: Object (mediaSource: "News Today", pageUrl: "https://www.newstoday.com", contents:)
 1:Object (mediaSource: "News Today", pageUrl: "https://www.newstoday.com", contents:)
 2:Object (mediaSource: "News Today", pageUrl: "https://www.newstoday.com", contents:)
 3:Object (mediaSource: "News Today", pageUrl: "https://www.newstoday.com", contents:)
```

My problem is.., How I want to get data in object to display in **HTML** page

**HTML**

```
<div class="media">
  <img class="mr-3" src="..." alt="Generic placeholder image">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-0">title here</h5>
    <span>url here</span>
    <div>
    contents here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is `res.data` an array of objects? if so then you can use `*ngFor` in your template.

Comment: @Ramesh but that `res.data` is available for the scope only which can't be used in HTML directly!

Comment: Yes `res.data is an array of objects... But how i want to make a difference let say..`mediaSource: "News Today" I want to display under title.` How should I do?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Of course, he needs to assign that to a new variable I'm just saying that he can use `*ngFor` structural directive because he has an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare a local variable and assign the response to that variable which can be available to use in HTML:

```
list: any[] = []; <-- here

FmtNews(mediasource) {
    let body = mediasource;
    console.log("Test body:" +body)
    this.commonService.getTopNews(body)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      if (res['status'].code === 102) {
         this.list = res['data'];
         console.log(res['data'])
      }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of list">
   {{obj.mediaSource}}
</div>
```

OR

if you want to display a `mediaSource` as a title then:

```
<div>{{ list[0]?.mediaSource }}</div>
```

which will display the first item's mediaSource property!

> **EDIT**

```
<div class="media" *ngFor="let obj of list">
  <img class="mr-3" src="..." alt="Generic placeholder image">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-0">{{ obj.mediaSource }}</h5>
    <span>{{ obj.pageUrl}}</span>
    <div>
    {{ obj.contents}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No.., I dont want like this...You can refer my question, i've edited it

Comment: I want to display all

Answer (score 1):

Store the data to a variable `this.data=res['data']`

In your HTML,

```
<div class="media">
  <img class="mr-3" src="..." alt="Generic placeholder image">
  <div class="media-body" *ngFor="let obj of data">
    <h5 class="mt-0">{{obj.mediaSource}}</h5>
    <span>{{obj.pageUrl}}</span>
    <div>{{obj.contents}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```